# Call another function on date picker text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form which have a jQuery calender. I want to call a price calculation function on

but if I call this function the # sign come into url and page goes to top.
if I remove onChange function the form working well, how it possible to remove # sign on call a function.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this, but depends on how you have written your code, please share more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JavaScript:void(0)

It will not get you to the top most line of the page ..

href="JavaScript:void(0)"

Comment: No its good but the calender put date onchange date. and i cant put <a> tag.